# Django: How to add a middleware which will return 200 when request method is OPTIONS

Tags: django

I have a requirement for testing purpose, whenever the `request.method == "OPTIONS"` then it should return status = 200.

How can a write a middleware for this in Django

Answer (score 0):

You can add status into the render

```
return render(request, 'template.html', status=200)
```

or even into the response

```
return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply,

```
def simple_middleware(get_response):
    def middleware(request):
        response = get_response(request)
        if request.method == "OPTIONS":
            response.status_code = 200
        return response

    return middleware
```

Comment: problem is sometimes there can be `exceptions raised from the view`, i.e some code error in the view

Comment: While sending the `OPTIONS` method? Thats strange